# Simplification of Binomial Expansion.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, power-series

How
$$(x+h)^n-x^n=nhx^{(n-1)}\text{ ?}$$

My attempt :

$$
\begin{align}
(x+h)^n-x^n & =nhx^{(n-1)} \\[8pt]
& =\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{(n-k)}h^k\right]-x^n \\[8pt]
& = \left[x^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{(n-k)}h^k\right]-x^n \\[8pt]
& =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{(n-k)}h^k
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You can never obtain the first equality (try to subtitute x, h, n by small numbers, and see)? The correct equality is what you have obtained in your attempt.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Rule_for_Derivatives/Natural_Number_Index#Theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing to try with these equations is induction, but I'm afraid in your case the equation is simply wrong: take $n=2$, $h=1$. We get $$(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1 \neq 2x=2hx^{n-1}$$